# Segmentation fault at MoveIt python tutorial

Tags: python, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow the python tutorial, but this simple file already crashes:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import copy
import rospy
import moveit_commander
import moveit_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg

print "============ Starting tutorial setup"
moveit_commander.roscpp_initialize(sys.argv)
rospy.init_node('move_group_python_interface_tutorial',
                anonymous=True)

robot = moveit_commander.RobotCommander()
```

And the result in a segmentation fault.

Here is a backtrace: http://pastebin.com/3bftAaaj

I am trying to get MoveIt to work with Amigo (https://github.com/tue-robotics/amigo_moveit_config). But I get the same error if I only have a roscore running. (No parameters loaded).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209207/segmentation-fault-at-moveit-python-tutorial/) by [Timple86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22432/timple86/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2015-05-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prrraveen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21441/prrraveen/) on 2015-07-25**:
I am having the same issue.Are you able to resolve it?

**Comment by [Timple86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22432/timple86/) on 2015-07-27**:
Nope, nobody replied here, nor on the github issue I created :-(.
Haven't found a solution yet.

**Comment by [gurusub90](https://answers.ros.org/users/25999/gurusub90/) on 2016-02-19**:
Me too! Did you find the solution for the issue?

**Comment by [gurusub90](https://answers.ros.org/users/25999/gurusub90/) on 2016-02-19**:
You have to go through the robot configuration for your specific robot. I have no idea why though!

**Comment by [Timple86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22432/timple86/) on 2016-02-20**:
I did follow the robot configuration wizard for Amigo. Still same issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This issue has been discussed at https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/pull/105

---

Originally posted by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) with karma: 1186 on 2016-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0